# Understanding primitive data types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, typeof null == “object” is true.
But null instanceOf Object is false. 
I was confused about this until I read in Professional JavaScript for Web Developers that,

> if instanceOf is used with a primitive value, it will always return FALSE, because primitives aren’t objects.

Why, if primitive data types aren't objects, will typeof null == "object" be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator is quirky, basically.  [Here is the documentation in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3). From that table, you can see that the operator is simply defined such that the result of `typeof null` is "object".

In JavaScript, `null` is really in a type of its own. It's a special primitive type.

JavaScript primitive types are indeed **not** objects. They can sometimes *seem* like objects, because the language semantics (specifically, the semantics of the `.` and `[ ]` operators) are such that primitives are automatically "boxed" with objects of a corresponding type. That's true for boolean, number, and string primitives. For `null`, there is no such corresponding object type.

Because of that,

```
var len = "some string".length;
```

works, even though string primitives don't have a "length" property.

One more thing: it's somewhat common to use the "toString" function on the Object prototype as a sort of "improved" version of the `typeof` operator.

```
alert( Object.prototype.toString.call( null ) ); // [object Null]
```

The strings that that function returns aren't the most convenient things to deal with, but they do provide a little finer granularity than `typeof`.

Comment: Fun fact - `typeof null` is a _mistake_ , they had an experiment to fix it a while ago and it didn't work because too many places relied on the current behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well it certainly seems like a mistake :)