# Why when I initialize an array of objects I still can push boolean values into it?

Tags: typescript

This is my TypeScript code:

```
const arr: {}[] = [{}];

arr.push(false);
```

For normal behave this will throw an error:

```
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'.
```

and I try some values of different types string, array, and work normally for normal use it needs to throw an error.

Comment: I tried `const falseObj: {} = false;` and it doesn't throw an error, there should be a spec about it I think

Comment: To get `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'.`, the type `arr` would have to be `{}[][]`, an array _of arrays_ of objects, but then `[{}]` wouldn't be valid as an initial value. `{}` isn't a very limiting type, read e.g. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492 for why you probably shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: `{}` is basically the most permissive type possible (except for `any`). It means *anything* that has at least no properties. Which is, essentially, everything. It does not mean "object".

Comment: Try `object` instead of `{}`.

Comment: i don't want an array of array of object, i want array of objects like this one :`` {}[]``

Comment: @YassineFarroud that doesn't mean "array of object", though.

Comment: For the reason [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77819402/why-when-i-initialize-an-array-of-objects-i-still-can-push-boolean-values-into-i#comment137189839_77819402).

Comment: The object syntax is only lower bound for what's acceptable: the type `{ foo: string; bar: number; }` would require anything with *at least*: one `foo` property which is a string, and one `bar` property which is a number. Thus `{foo: "hello, bar: 42, baz: true}` fulfils the criteria. `{ foo: string }` means *at least*: one property which is called `foo` and is a string. An object that fits the first limitation would also fit the second one. Thus working downwards `{}` means anything with at least no properties. Since basically every value has at least no properties, even booleans are valid.

Comment: That's mean anything in js is object ?

Comment: `false.hello` isn't an error, just `undefined`! Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547024/3001761 - I think `null` is the _only_ thing `{}` rules out.

Comment: @YassineFarroud no, it means anything can have a property. Again, `{}` does **not** mean an object. Consider the type `{ length: number }` - that will allow, for example the value `["a", "b", "c"]` which is an array (thus an object) and has `length`. However, a string is a primitive value, yet *also* has a `length`. However, say, a number doesn't have a `length` property. https://tsplay.dev/N7G0qN